# Strange "Binding overwriting" in logs

Tags: gnome, 19.04, log

I'm looking for a reason for freezes of the system. Just before the freeze I've got such lines in the logs:

```
cен 06 09:03:31 keddad-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1896]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
сен 06 09:03:31 keddad-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1896]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
сен 06 09:03:31 keddad-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1896]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
сен 06 09:03:31 keddad-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1896]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
сен 06 09:03:31 keddad-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1896]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
сен 06 09:03:31 keddad-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1896]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
сен 06 09:03:31 keddad-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1896]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
сен 06 09:03:31 keddad-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1896]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
сен 06 09:03:31 keddad-pc org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1896]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
```

What are these? What kind of binding does it overwrite and why? Can it cause be the reason for freezes?
UPD: These things appear to happen after each boot

Comment: it looks exactly like this issue on dash-to-dock:
https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/648

Comment: I have this issue whenever xdotool fires.

Comment: Did you ever resolve the freeze issue?

Comment: @foaly it just dissipated with some update, I guess

Comment: Seems a duplicate of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1062455/349837), and [this bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/issues/606) (also [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1857392))